# Adding data to QML TreeView

Tags: qt, qml, treeview, listmodel

I'm developing an application. I need to add data to TreeView but I have some problems with TreeView's nested model.

I created a List Model which is

```
ListModel {
    id: fruitModel
    ListElement {
       name: "Apple"
       price: 2.45
    }
}
```

I am able to show this item by the way of

```
TreeView {
    id: mytreeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: fruitModel
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "name"
        width: 200
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Price"
        role: "price"
        width: 200
    }
}
```

However , I need to show nested items like

```
ListModel {
   ListElement {
            categoryName: "Fruits"
            collapsed: true
            subItems: [
                ListElement { itemName: "Orange" , itemPrice: 2.40},
                ListElement { itemName: "Apple" ,  itemPrice: 2.40},
                ListElement { itemName: "Pear" ,   itemPrice: 2.40},
                ListElement { itemName: "Lemon" ,  itemPrice: 2.40}
            ]
    }
}
```

I listed these items in ListView but I need to list these items in TreeView. So, how can I list this nested ListModel in TreeView using QML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to correct the roles to match your new nested model/ListElement's scope/roles. And build your model correctly (you using "," for ListElement items .. use ";") as corrected below.

Second , use `listmodel` function  [*object get(index)*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method)  to iterate down and lockup the nested model.

THis will work!:

```
ListModel {
    id:fruitModel
    ListElement {
        categoryName: "Fruits"
        collapsed: true
        subItems: [
            ListElement { itemName: "Orange" ; itemPrice: 2.40},
            ListElement { itemName: "Apple" ;  itemPrice: 2.40},
            ListElement { itemName: "Pear" ;   itemPrice: 2.40},
            ListElement { itemName: "Orange" ;  itemPrice: 2.40}
        ]
    }
    ListElement {
        categoryName: "Vegetable"
        collapsed: true
        subItems: [
            ListElement { itemName: "Broccoli" ; itemPrice: 4.20},
            ListElement { itemName: "Garlic" ;  itemPrice: 7.40},
            ListElement { itemName: "beens" ;   itemPrice: 6.40},
            ListElement { itemName: "Eggplant" ;  itemPrice: 1.40}
        ]
    }
}
TreeView {
    id: mytreeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model:fruitModel.get(0).subItems  // get nested model this way , or by Javascript! 
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "itemName"   // here
        width: 200
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Price"
        role: "itemPrice"   // here 
        width: 200
    }
    //Component.onCompleted: model= fruitModel.get(0).subItems
}
```

**UpDate**:

To display multiple nested elements , you can use `section` property with `ListView` and display nested model with `TreeView` :

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: fruitModel
    delegate: nameDelegate
    focus: true
    highlight: Rectangle {
        color: "lightblue"
        width: parent.width
    }
    section {
        property: "categoryName"
        criteria: ViewSection.FullString
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: "#b0dfb0"
            width: parent.width
            height: childrenRect.height + 4
            Text { anchors.left: parent.left
                font.pixelSize: 16
                font.bold: true
                text: section
            }
        }
    }
}
Component {
    id: nameDelegate
    TreeView {
        id: mytreeView
        width: parent.width
        model:fruitModel.get(index).subItems  // get nested model
        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "itemName"   // here
            width: 200
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Price"
            role: "itemPrice"   // here
            width: 200
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not rely on `get(int)` on a `ListModel` unless you are pretty d**n sure, you never want to use that pice of code in an Application that evolved to use C++ defined models. The standard C++ models do not provide that function. Providing that function on a C++ model is not entierly trivial (many people return a map of properties, which is ok for read-only but won't work if you want to use the object to modify the model). That said, I have no knowledge on the tree view, no Qt enviornment running, so I can't provide a solution. Just be aware of that potential problem!

Comment: @derM, thanks for the advice. I have a functional application where the model is populated entirely in QML  .. all user entry is stored in individual elements having nested _attribues_ .. these attributes are displayed (one at a time) but then do not go further than that .. each element is passed to a parent model for retention and JSON stringification. This is  handy as far as the coder knows what he is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the solution however, I want to show the category name in my tree with subitems. How can I show my subitems with the category name? Also, I will have multiple items in my list model. How can I add multiple ListModel items to my tree? Can you help me about this?

Comment: @HilalKöktürk , depends how you plan the display to look like  ... do you want to display your entire model as expandable tree view ? or your only concern is to list contents by order

Comment: I want to display my entire model as expandable tree view

Comment: @HilalKöktürk,  Check Qt _views_ example , it has a variety of solutions. The "Expanding Delegates" part fits for your model. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-views-example.html#expanding-delegates

Comment: I think this answer is not what the OP wants. And neither "Expanding Delegates" is what OP wants. OP wants a model suitable for displaying a **tree** in the TreeView.